# Demonstration that every finite set is computable

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

What is the best demonstration that show that "Every finite set is computable"?

thanks

Comment: [You should be able to figure out the answer from this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set)

Comment: Are you offering criteria for "best"? There is a simple, sensible answer (which has been given as an answer below), does this fit your criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any finite set, it's trivial to write a program that accepts exactly the members of the set: just compare the input against each element of the set in turn.